# Settings API enable default settings on theme install?

Tags: theme-development, settings-api

I am still learning settings API so please forgive my noob question. I have three fields: a checkbox, colorpicker and text field (they are **working**), but I would like to do this:
when the theme is installed add **"checked" state** to my checkbox but allow user to "unchecked" it ,and if empty add **default color** to my colorpicker... I have no idea how to do this so please help me!

My code looks like this now (**thanks** to @Chip Bennett! ) :

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu','create_theme_options_page');
function create_theme_options_page(){
add_options_page('Theme Options','Theme Options','administrator',__FILE__,'build_options_page');
}
   function build_options_page(){
   ?>
   <div id="theme-options-wrap">
   <div style="float:left;margin-top:19px;position:absolute;" class="icon32" id="icon-tools"><br/></div>
   <h2>My options page</h2>
   <form method="post" action="options.php">
   <?php settings_fields('plugin_options');?>
   <?php do_settings_sections(__FILE__); ?>
   <p class="submit">
   <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save changes');?>"/>
   </p>
   </form>
   </div>
   <?php
   }

     add_action('admin_init','register_and_build_fields');
     function register_and_build_fields(){
     register_setting('plugin_options','plugin_options','validate_setting');
     add_settings_section('main_section','<br/><br/>Main Settings','section_cb',__FILE__);
     add_settings_field('banner_heading','Banner Heading:','banner_heading_setting',__FILE__,'main_section');
     add_settings_field('display_sidebar','Display Sidebar:','display_sidebar_setting',__FILE__,'main_section');
     add_settings_field('display_colorpicker','Display Colorpicker:','display_colorpicker_setting',__FILE__,'main_section');
     }
       //Install Iris colorpicker
       add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'mw_enqueue_color_picker' );
       function mw_enqueue_color_picker( $hook_suffix ) {
       // first check that $hook_suffix is appropriate for your admin page
       wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
       wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-handle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js', array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true );
       }

         //Colorpicker
         //Now how to add a default color on theme install?
         function display_colorpicker_setting(){
         $options = get_option('plugin_options');
         echo"<input type='text' id='color1' name='plugin_options[display_colorpicker]' value='{$options['display_colorpicker']}'/>";
         }

          //Sidebar checkbox
          //Now how to add a default state "checked" on theme install?
          function display_sidebar_setting(){
          $options = get_option('plugin_options');
          echo "<input type='checkbox' name='plugin_options[display_sidebar]' {$options['display_sidebar']} id='display_sidebar' />";
          }

            //Banner Heading
            function banner_heading_setting(){
            $options = get_option('plugin_options');
            echo "<input name='plugin_options[banner_heading]' type='text' value='{$options['banner_heading']}'/>";
            }
              //Validate our settings here
              function validate_setting($plugin_options){   
              return $plugin_options;
              }

               function section_cb(){
               }
?>
```

Comment: Please, don't post "flat" code. Use indentation to format your code. No one will read that.

Comment: Hope it is better now?

Comment: Ehm... Thanks for your effort, but you should really read about this somewhere. :)

Comment: @DejoDekic, see http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass defaults to [`get_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option).  The second parameter is a fallback.

> `$default`
>       (mixed) (optional) The default value to return if no value is returned (ie. the option is not in the database).
>
> ```
>     Default: false
> ```

So, for example, instead of:

```
  $options = get_option('plugin_options');
```

You'd want:

```
  $options = get_option('plugin_options',array('display_sidebar' => true));
```

Or you can insert your default options with [`add_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option), which is "A safe way of adding a named option/value pair to the options database table. It does nothing if the option already exists."

I'd do the latter. It should be easier.

Comment: This stumped me for half a day. The idea that the default could be an array of key/pairs never occured to me.